# Any way to create a catch all Route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have many actions on a controller

```
Controller1\Action1
Controller1\Action2
Controller1\Action3
Controller1\Action4
Controller1\Action5
Controller1\Action6
```

I would like my URLs to always be just:

```
Action1
Action2
Action3
Action4
Action5
Action6
```

Is there an easy way to do this?  I won't have any conflicts where:

```
Controller1\Action1
Controller2\Action1
```

Every action will have a unique name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CatchAll",
    "{action}/{*path}",
    new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index" }
);
```

Essentially you're telling it all requests should treat the path as the Action and they should all go to "MyController". The action = "Index" acts as a default in the event that an Action is not provided in the Url.

The above route definition will evaluate to true even if extra, invalid path data is appended after the action name. What that means is that both `/Action1` and `/Action1/251958125ad/2512qsadfa2` will go to `Action1()`. If you would prefer that only the exact path be allowed:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CatchAll",
    "{action}",
    new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index" }
);
```