# Handling errors/exceptions in MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, error-handling

As well as many other, I'm trying to create my own MVC to improve my knowledge etc. :)
I'd like to ask about handling errors/exceptions in MVC pattern.

`Dispatcher` is getting information from `Router` about `Route` and getting `Controller`'s and method's name from `Route`. Then dispatcher is trying to create instance of this `Controller` and execute this method.

Now let's imagine that our method is throwing exception (yes, it is not catched in method because of bad code :)). It could be custom made exception like `NotFoundException` or `ApplicationInternalErrorException` or one of SPL excpetions like `RuntimeErrorException` or `InvalidArgumentException`. It doesn't matter, really.

Of course, we want `Dispatcher` catch this exception, log it and respond accordingly exception type: display 404 page if `NotFoundException` was catched etc.

What is the best practice for doing it? Is `Dispatcher` a right place for doing it? Maybe the best place is `FrontController` (but I'm not using this pattern; `Dispatcher` is creating `Controller` instance.

Simple code:

```
class Dispatcher {

    public function dispatch() {

        $controller = $this->getRouter()->getController();
        $method     = $this->getRouter()->getMethod();
        $args       = $this->getRouter()->getArguments();

        try {
            call_user_func_array(array($controller, $method), array_values($args));                
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Logger::log($e->__toString);
            if ($e instanceof NotFoundPage) {
                call_user_func(array('ErrorController', 'notFound'))
            } elseif ($e instanceof ...) {
               ...
            } elseif ($e instanceof ...) {
               ...
            } else {
               ...
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Is it ok, or it is not a very good practice?

Thank you.

Comment: if the method does not exist, how will it know to throw that exception? are you going to use __call in all of your controllers to throw the exception?

Comment: seems like you may want to simply check if the controller and action exist before trying to run them, and redirect to 404 if not. also, does getController() return an actual instance of the class?

Comment: You can catch all routes in MVC and point it to your 404 page.
Take a look on this similar post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766321/any-way-to-create-a-catch-all-route

Answer (score 0):

I'm simply using an external file (xml, yaml or anything you like) which contains all the routes for my web application. When a request comes the Router tries to match the request url to one of the routes I have in my file. If there were no match it simply redirects to the 404 page with a 404 header. I think that you don't need try/catch blocks for this.

I took the idea from Symfony.